# ジョブをプロバイダーに登録しようとする際、bindMethod()がundefinedになる。

Tags: php, laravel

laravelで勤怠管理システムをつくっています。
毎日24時に勤務終了と、勤務開始を自動で打刻する機能をつくるにあたって、
スケジュールのサンプルコードを書いたのですが、プロバイダへのジョブの登録時にbindMethod()という
コンテナにあるはずのメソッドがundefindeになってしまいます。
「laravel実践開発」という書籍に従って作成したので、間違ってはいないはずなのですが、原因が分かりません。
侍テラコヤという有料サービスで聞いたのですが、分からないとのことでした。
どなたか分かる方いらっしゃれば、ご教示いただければ幸いです。

githubのURLです。
https://github.com/akirasasakiatgithub/attendance

Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use App\Jobs\automaticStamp;
use App\Jobs\testStampJob;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use App\Model\Rest;
use App\Models\Attendance;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;


class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{

    protected $commands = [
        //
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $id = Auth::id();
            $schedule->call(new testStampJob($id))->everyMinute();
    }
}
```

testStampJob.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\Rest;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class testStampJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;


    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }


    public function __invoke()
    {
        $this->handle();
    }
    
    public function handle()
    {
        //休憩時間記録用のモデルに休憩開始時刻を打刻
        $now = Carbon::now();
        Rest::create([
            'date' => $now->format('Y-m-d'),
            'start_break' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'id_u' => $this->id,
        ]);

        //開始時刻に1秒加えて休憩終了時刻を打刻
        Rest::create([
            'date' => $now->addSecond()->format('Y-m-d'),
            'end_break' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'id_u' => Auth::id()
        ]);
    }
}
```

testStampProvider.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Jobs\testStampJob;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class testStampProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bindMethod([testStampJob::class, 'handle'], function($job, $app) {
            return $job->handle();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

推測ですが、

- *OK* コマンドの実行自体は行える。実行時にエラーが発生したりはしない。
- *NG* エディタ上で警告が表示される。

おそらく以上の状況ですよね？だとしたら気にしなくて大丈夫です。
*NG* の箇所はLaravelの既知の問題で、おそらくLaravel10で修正されます。

[[10.x] Add `bindMethod` method by mahmoudmohamedramadan · Pull Request #43168 · laravel/framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/43168)

ただそれとは別の理由で、今の実装だと意図通りの動きにならない気がします。

- スケジュールの冒頭で `Auth::id()` で対象ユーザーを拾っているがブラウザアクセスではないので「認証」自体が行われていない。そのため特に意味のない処理になっている。（登録対象は誰なのか、別の方法で特定する実装が必要）
- Kernel でのタスク実行時はサービスコンテナを使わず自力で初期化しているのでKernelへ実装した `bindMethod()` はそもそも呼ばれていない（おそらくこの処理は不要）

難しいかもしれませんが頑張ってくださいー。

Comment: 回答していただいていることに長らく気づかず申し訳ありません。スケジュールやジョブなど未だ消化しきれておらず、検討させていただいてからお答えさせていただきます。ひとまず、ブラウザアクセスではないので、Auth::IDは無効というのは理解できました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: 上手くいきました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: よかったです！！